# Display video on asp.net form

Tags: webforms, ado.net, video-streaming

My application is allowing users to upload videos(avi and wmv) and then those videos should be displayed on users home page. Uploaded file is saved on server and path to the file is saved in database. 
What is the best way to display those videos on page?
I'm using ASP.NET forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net does not have any video or media controls natively. Some people have tried the MediaPlayer control, however this is an ActiveX control so browser compatibility is a major issue. Depending on what formats you are accepting a variety of solutions from simple to complicated exist and can be broken down to two categories:

**HTML5 Video**
You can use the basic HTML5 Video, depending on what formats you have (avi, mp4, oog, etc.) you will need to have multiple source files for compatiblity across all browsers.

A list of compatible formats for each browser can be found here:[W3 Schools HTML5 Video Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

You can add runat="server" and access the properties directly. I've found adding multiple sources requires setting inner text and adding a new src tag.

**Third Party Tools**
These can be great for cross-browser compatibility and include FlowPlayer, Telerik's Media Player Control, jVideo and others. Solutions like FlowPlayer can fallback to Flash in the event a browser is not compatible with the format and still play. Some are free, some are not. You can wrap a control without server-side methods (FlowPlayer) into a user control depending on what you need.